# Google Sign-In for iOS crash?

Tags: ios, google-signin

In an iOS project that uses Google Sign-In SDK (v5.0.2, added manually to the project, as well as GTM and Firebase), we have a crash that we could reproduce several times with a specific account on a specific device, when trying to sign in with a Google account.

The crash is:

```
** Assertion failure in +[UIAlertAction _actionWithTitle:descriptiveText:image:style:handler:shouldDismissHandler:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3901.4.5/UIAlertAction.m:42
```

The stack trace says the crash appears in

```
+[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:style:handler:]
-[GIDEMMErrorHandler passcodeRequiredAlertWithCompletion:] + 556
-[GIDEMMErrorHandler handleErrorFromResponse:completion:]_block_invoke + 724
```

Poking with the debugger, it looks like `UIAlertAction` is passed a `nil` title, which causes an assertion failure.

The OS of the device is iOS 13.3.1.

I can't find an official way to report a bug in the Google Sign-In SDK, the Google issue tracker seems to be restricted to people with specific permissions, and they otherwise point to a forum that doesn't exist anymore, or to Stack Overflow...

Comment: We're having this issue too, and we are considering to use the older versions of the SDK at this point...

Comment: I cannot figure out where I can open a ticket about this, either. I will file an issue at github project...

Comment: Nope, the github issues doesn't seem to be the right place to file this... bummer

Comment: The best I could do is reporting this via Firebase support. :S

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the resource bundle isn't being correctly linked in your project so the SDK gets a `nil` string for the action dialog which triggers the crash.

Until Google will gracefully fix it by providing a fallback string you can verify how you are linking the `GoogleSignIn.bundle` in your project

[image: screenshot]